# how to check the checkbox inside the repeater at binding time accordingto value?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater, findcontrol, itemdatabound

I have a repeater and inside it i have a checkbox. Now i want to check it according to columns value(0/1). I have tried it through the itemDataBound event of the repeater. what its doing if the rows has value 1 then its checked all checkbox and if first checkbox is unchecked then its unchecked all. 
my code is:-
`

```
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>`
```

The ItemDataBound events code is :-

```
 protected void rp_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = obj.abc(id);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)(e.Item.FindControl("chk"));
        if (chk != null)
        {

            if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["xyz"]) == Convert.ToInt32("0"))
            {
                chk.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                chk.Checked = true;

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

1. You can write inline ASP.NET:

   ```
   <asp:CheckBox id='isMarried' runat='server' 
   Checked='<%# Convert.ToBool(Eval("IsMarried")) ? true : false %>' />
   ```
2. As you have mentioned, you can use `repeater_ItemDataBound` to find the check-box of each row, and set its value accordingly:

   ```
   protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
   {
       Person person = (Person)e.Item; // e.Item is the datasoruce of the row
       if (person.IsMarried) 
       {
           CheckBox isMarried = (CheckBox)(e.Item.FindControl("isMarried"));
           isMarried.Checked = true;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Another way could be to inject the Boolean state (here, the marriage state) in a hidden field and send it to the client, then on client-side, using jQuery (or any other JavaScript framework), update check-boxes' checked state according to the value of those hidden fields:

Comment: I don't know if it's something about newer version but on Visual Studio for Mac that need to be:

Person person = (Person)e.Item.DataItem;

or

var person = (Person)e.Item.DataItem;